# I create a tmp struct in a while loop,but some error happen,it looks like the tmp struct not be free at one loop end

Tags: c++, memory, struct

[image: 1]I create a tmp struct in a while loop,but some error happen,it looks like the tmp struct not be free at one loop end,but when I create a struct pointer，it works.

```
class Solution {
```

public:
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
struct ListNode node;

```
    ListNode* head= &node;
    ListNode* h=head;
    int sum=0;
    bool carry=false;
    while(l1!=NULL||l2!=NULL)
    {
        sum=0;
        if(l1!=NULL)
        {
            sum+=l1->val;
            l1=l1->next;
        }
        if(l2!=NULL)
        {
            sum+=l2->val;
            l2=l2->next;
        }
        if(carry)
            sum++;
        struct ListNode tmp;
        tmp.val=sum%10;
        tmp.next=NULL;
        // cout<<&tmp<<endl;
        // h->next=new ListNode(sum%10);
        h->next=&tmp;
        h=h->next;
        
        // delete h->next;
        carry=sum>=10?true:false;
    }
    if(carry)
    {
        h->next=new ListNode(1);
    }
    return head->next;

}
```

};

Comment: You are trying to assign address of  local variable in a block to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see that it is a local variable so that when the next loop, h use its address and find the memroy has been free. Instead，when I use malloc,the struct is in heap,so it work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may because you are creating `tmp` on the stack inside the `while` loop, then assigning it's address to `h->next`.  As soon as the `while` loop iteration ends, `tmp` is no longer in scope, but you have stored a reference to it inside `h`.  You need to create `tmp` on the heap for this to work, as you have discovered by creating it as a pointer I suspect.

Comment: Thank You! That is the reason.